# How to extract year and date out of a string in R

Tags: regex, r, date

I have a list of character with entries such as "31DEC2005". I want to extract the year as integer 2005, as well as date month "31DEC" out of it. Please suggest a method. Thanks.

Comment: Are there functions in `r` like left(), mid(), right(), substring()? Did you research *any* of this? I don't know `r` but imagine I could find this out in under a minute.

Comment: I searched for date functions and tried for like 20 minutes before posting the question. If I knew the answer, definitely I would not have posted.

Comment: Just running `?Date` in the R console shows an example using the `format` function & `?date` would have given an even better `format` example. Where did you search?

Comment: This question might not show a lot of research, but one should remember that SO is a help site for programmers. To me this question contains enough information for a correct answer, the focus is within the framework of SO, and thus is sufficient. I do not question the decision of closing the question as there are probably tons of duplicates, but I do not agree with people down-voting here. It is just cruel to punish people for not knowing a solution that might be considered simple by experienced users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative to extract the year as integer:

```
x <- c("31DEC2005", "28FEB2012", "16JUL2002", "01JAN2007")
sub("[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+","", x)
#[1] "2005" "2012" "2002" "2007"
```

Date-month is easiest to extract from @bartektartanus's solution using date functions in `data.table` package for instance:

```
y <- as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
library(data.table)
month(y)
#[1] 12  2  7  1
mday(y)
#[1] 31 28 16  1
paste(mday(y), month(y), sep = "-")
#[1] "31-12" "28-2"  "16-7"  "1-1"
```

This solution would also work for year:

```
year(y)
#[1] 2005 2012 2002 2007
```

Comment: Note that there are plenty of ways doing date conversions in R. One very nice package for this purpose is `lubridate` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 2):

See `?substr`:

`substr("31DEC2005",1,5)`

To automate:

```
start<-c(1,3,6) 
stop<-c(2,5,9)
lapply(seq(1,3),function(i)substr("31DEC2005",start[i],stop[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that maybe function Date is better than regex, try:

```
as.Date("31DEC2005", "%d%b%Y")
```